# Suitable test for determining the change in average

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

I have faced several schools of thoughts for determining the mean change. I'll discuss the solutions starting with the simplest one but first I want to provide you with an example data:

```
      site year2011 year2012
1   site 1       14       64
2   site 2       22       44
3   site 3      104      148
4   site 4      242      314
5   site 5       48       68
6   site 6      158      206
7   site 7      126      150
8   site 8      244      288
9   site 9      356      514
10 site 10      264      298
11 site 11      144      184
12 site 12      246      310
13 site 13       64       84
```

The data above are collected for a total of 13 locations twice- first in 2011 and second time in 2012. The numbers indicate concentrations of an element in the air. The aim is to conclude whether overall there has been a mean change of the element's concentration after a year.

First approach: This approach takes the average (& standard deviation) for all sites (n=13) in 2011 and 2012, which are 156 (sd:107) and 206 (sd:135), respectively. If we take 95% confidence interval i.e. 2*sd/square root of n; then we get 156+/-59 for 2011 and 206+/-75 for 2012. Since the deviations from the mean of the two surveys overlap, the conclusion is that the mean concentration of the element haven't not change over a year.

Second approach: This approach adopt paired t-test based on the assumption that surveys were done at the same locations at different times. Paired t-test (I used t.test function of R programming language) gives a p-value < 0.001 indicating there has been significant change in the average concentration of the element in air over time! The equations used in this test can be found [here](http://www.statstutor.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/paired-t-test.pdf)

```
Paired t-test
data:  a$year2011 and a$year2012
t = -4.8569, df = 12, p-value = 0.0003936
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -71.31598 -27.14556
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
              -49.23077
```

Third approach: This approach similarly relies on t-test but its called 'Welch Two Sample t-test'. The assumption here: although the same sites were investigated one year apart they were measuring the concentrations from different samples (because air moves) i.e. the locations/sites are fixed but the measurements were done in two different samples. Paired t-test should be performed on the same sample (needs to be dependent). This approach requires the use of equations [here](http://ccnmtl.columbia.edu/projects/qmss/the_ttest/twosample_ttest.html) and the final result (below) shows a p-value > 0.05 indicating the mean concentration of the element didn't change significantly! This test supports the simplest (first) approach.

```
Welch Two Sample t-test
data:  a$year2011 and a$year2012
t = -1.0295, df = 22.769, p-value = 0.3141
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -148.21209   49.75055
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 156.3077  205.5385
```

My question is: which approach of determining mean change in concentration is the most suitable for the given problem and why not the other approaches?

Comment: The data are paired (on the individual stores). Only one of your analyses considers that.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me -- why would them being "from the same inventory" or not be relevant to the question about a change in mean? Also for some reason I seem to have lost my second sentence from the original comment (possibly an accidental deletion; the trackpad sometimes plays up) -- you also have *counts* so you probably don't actually want a t-test either.

Comment: Don't ask a new question in comments, *fix your post*. [When people "make up" a problem that's only kind of like their actual problem, they often don't know enough about what is essential and what is not to get the answer they need -- made up problems often waste time or get useless answers, because they omit or change aspects that are important to the statistical issues that need to be considered. Soil properties can have very different issues than counts of products in stores.]  If you have a substantively different question, you should probably ask about that.

Comment: I updated the question to make it more relevant